# which open source project(s) uses the castle activerecord?

Tags: .net, castle-activerecord

Rather than the demos can you suggest any open source projects using castle activerecord for code study?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are quite a few on [google code](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=castle%20activerecord). Some of them are:

- [winecellarmanager](http://code.google.com/p/winecellarmanager/)
- [mr-blogengine](http://code.google.com/p/mr-blogengine/)
- [storyverse](http://code.google.com/p/storyverse/)
- [gaia-sprint](http://code.google.com/p/gaia-sprint/)
- [Storm the Castle](http://code.google.com/p/storm-the-castle/)
- [Issuetracker.Net](http://code.google.com/p/issuetrackerdotnet/)

Comment: Do any of these show a use of complex queries or optimized updates?  They all seem like simple projects.

Comment: Wish they were hosted somewhere else than google code. Because google does not allow me to access them. Just because I'm from Iran.

Comment: @afsharm: can you use a proxy, to simulate a different location?

Comment: @Mauricio: I used Tor but didn't succeed. Such tools are really confusing.

Comment: @afsharm: the Vidalia bundle has everything you need. You can ask any questions about Tor on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tor

Comment: @afsharm: this might also help you: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/dear-nigerians-help-us-help-you