# Sample Application(s) using Castle ActiveRecord?

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord, castle-activerecord

I have been trying to track down some sample applications that are using Castle ActiveRecord.

Do you know of any good sample applications?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327475/which-open-source-projects-uses-the-castle-activerecord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problems with Castle Active Record is the lack of basic Examples and the Lack of Documentation.  I used it on a project once, and I literally spent about 60% of my time trying to figure out how to do what I wanted to do:  googling constantly picking up snippets in blogs here and there....

If you are in the same boat then stop now - NHibernate is a little harder to learn, but you'll get there a lot faster as there is a wealth of information both online and at your local book shop!

Comment: Given that it's open source, don't you have the option of making the situation better?

Comment: -1 I agree with Michael Maddox, plus I already pointed that this is a duplicate question and there are *lots* of sample projects listed in the other question.