# How run Castle Active REcord Example

Tags: c#, castle-activerecord

I can't run properly example from castle site under VS2010 +mssql2008 (I try it under ms win xp - mssql2005 +ms c# 2010 express too)

...

// We are using XmlConfigurationSource:
 XmlConfigurationSource source = new XmlConfigurationSource("appconfig.xml");

ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize( source, typeof(Blog), typeof(Post), typeof(User) );
...

at Initialize in app.cs module an exception :
{"The type initializer for 'NHibernate.LoggerProvider' threw an exception."}

Inner exception:

{"Unrecognized configuration section config. (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\bin\BlogSample.vshost.exe.Config line 3)"}

What wrong?
xml config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="activerecord"
                 type="Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Config.ActiveRecordSectionHandler, Castle.ActiveRecord" />
  </configSections>

  <activerecord isWeb="false" pluralizeTableNames="true">

    <config>
      <add key="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" />
      <add key="hibernate.dialect"                 value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect" />
      <add key="hibernate.connection.provider"     value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
      <add key="hibernate.connection.connection_string"  value="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Gecko1#1.sdf;Password=ghbdtn185" />
    </config>

  </activerecord>

</configuration>
```

Befor this I was try

```
 < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
< activerecord isWeb="false" pluralizeTableNames="true">
  < config>
    < add key="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" />
    < add key="hibernate.dialect"                 value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect" />
    < add key="hibernate.connection.provider"     value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
    < add key="hibernate.connection.connection_string"  value="Data  Source=|DataDirectory|\Gecko1#1.sdf;Password=ghbdtn185" />
  < /config>
< /activerecord>
```

But I get:

{"Configuration system failed to initialize"}

Answer (score 0):

That sample code is *very* old (originally VS2003). I recommend using one of [these projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327475/which-open-source-projects-uses-the-castle-activerecord) as reference, although that list is also somewhat old by now (but not as old as the sample code)

Comment: I select that example between it simple first step for learn Castle active record, but I lost some time for try do it work... I get some misterious error